# pg_dump returning no rows

Tags: postgresql, export, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

usually I have good luck with pg_dump getting dumps of table data, but for some reason, it always returns zero rows for one of them.

Here is the command I use that usually works

```
pg_dump -d foo_db -h localhost -p 8888 -U postgres -t foo_table --column-inserts --data-only > foo.sql
```

port, db, login are all good

Here's the results:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

--
-- Data for Name: foo_table; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--



--
-- Name: foo_table_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('foo_table_id_seq', 179, true);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

I can log into the db and see the rows are in there, but pg_dump can't get them for some reason

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 8888 -d foo_db

You are now connected to database "foo_db" as user "postgres".
foo_db=# select count(*) from foo_table;
 count 
-------
   116
(1 row)

Time: 30.972 ms
```

Comment: It looks weird. But `pg_dump` does not accept a `-d` switch, so the command you mention can't be exactly the actual command producing that result. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: pg_dump --help ... pg_dump --help
pg_dump dumps a database as a text file or to other formats.

Usage:
  pg_dump [OPTION]... [DBNAME]

... 
Connection options:
  -d, --dbname=DBNAME      database to dump
...

Comment: So it's not pg_dump from postgresql-9.2. `pg_dump --version` would tell.

Comment: updated tag to postgresql-9.4

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I am having the same problem as you...